# Django File Upload with more than 6 MB thru admin - this website is not available

Tags: django, file-upload, virtualhost

I am trying to upload a file thru admin page, the size of the file is over 6 MB, once i try to upload, i am getting: `This website is not available`. I opened in FF and saw this error message in browser:

```
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading
```

I tried to change the file upload max size in http.conf in this way:

```
<Directory "/usr/local/httpd/mypage/path/to/media/uploadfolder">
     LimitRequestBody 104857600
</Directory>
```

I am in virtualhost server.

this change didnot succeed, what should i do now?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, no error log because the page is reloading and error log is almost empty

Comment: How much does your packet sniffer show going through? To share my thoughts, this is not a Django problem. There is some network tool or configuration that is interacting badly with the contents of the file.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah, i think also so,.. this is not django issue. this is rather server issue which probably doesnot like big files.. :(

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i tried to upload the same pdf file to other pdf minize online tools, they are also saying: ``"this website is not available"``. i think, something is wrong with my pdf file, right?

Comment: Or with something towards your side of the network.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah